# How to fix sandbox violations by airportd?

Tags: macos, airport, sandbox

I keep seeing a lot of errors like this in the console which seem to be causing beachballs:

```
SandboxViolation: airportd(81) deny(1) file-read-metadata /Users
```

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012) and I'm running version 10.12.4.

Answer (score 1):

Those sandbox violations aren't ever something that causes a beachball in my experience. They may be logged at the same time, but are coincidence and will happen when the beach ball isn't in progress.

- To dig in to the beachball - which app is spinning or are all?
- Can you run a sysdiagnose (in activity monitor) on the app?

Comment: It's usually a browser or Mail.app that's giving me the beachball. I just ran sysdiagnose from the Activity Monitor, but I'm not sure how to interpret it now

Comment: @2daaa Most people need to send that file to Apple or pay a technician to look it over. If you can reproduce the beach all with the network off - that would be something that’s totally a local issue. If you need the internet to block things - then there’s your answer to do less network tasks